# Parallel forloop with unknown quantity of steps

Tags: go

I am learning Go. I have a for loop with recursive steps until several things (unknown quantity) are found among an unknown quantity of items. 
I want to use the `go func()` to be able to speed up the search.
I am using the `chan` and `chan <-` `<-chan` to monitor the workers. However I dont know how to wait for the job to be done and be able to use the found items.

Thank you !

Comment: A code sample would clarify your intention better.

Answer (score 0):

Wait groups are useful here.

Declare a variable and add a wait group:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)
```

Defer the wait group finishing inside your go routine and block outside it:

```
go func(){
    //your function here. If you want a for loop with go routines put it outside the go routine
    defer wg.Done()
}()

wg.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct about the `sync.WaitGroup` is the tool to use here. The `for` loop IMHO is misplaced, I think you are about to process items in a loop concurrently; like this:

```
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for item := range sourceOfUnknownQuantity {
        wg.Add(1)
        go process(item, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func process(item int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // process item
}

var (
    sourceOfUnknownQuantity = make(chan int)
)
```

Using `sourceOfUnknownQuantity` in the `for` loop is just for demonstration. Your implementation of loop might differ.